# Unity3D relative offset object rotation using quaternions

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I don't know how to solve this in Unity3D.

Example: User a) performs a 90 degrees clockwise manipulation on the object ->  Object b) should automatically adjust its orientation i.e. also perform a 90 degrees clockwise rotation **relative to its current orientation**. So, both objects have a different end-orientation. I have to use quaternions.

Example:
[image]

I have tried the following things:

```
float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, quatObjectA, Time.time * speed);
```

and

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(ransform.rotation, quatObjectA, Time.time * speed);
```

-> Object a) and b) have the same end-orientation, not what I want (for both approaches)

```
transform.rotation = transform.rotation*quatObjectA;
```

-> Results in some weird and wrong lagging motion

I want to calculate the difference between the current and goal orientation of object a) and apply the same rotation to object b) with respect to its current orientation.

---

#### Solved

I have figured it out. It is actually kind of obvious.

```
    Quaternion relativeB = Quaternion.Inverse(ObjectBOld) * ObjectBNew;
    transform.rotation = transform.rotation*relativeB;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
ObjectB.transform.position = ObjectA.transform.right * someOffsetX
  + ObjectA.transform.up* someOffsetY
  + ObjectA.transform.forward * someOffsetZ;
```

Or make B a child of A.

Comment: Thank you Draco18s. However, I do not want to change the position of the object. I only talk about changing the orientation. A child also does not work for me since object a) is not suppose to follow object a) all the time -> it is triggered by an event.

Comment: That was hard to get from your post, but it looks like you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to set a static offset on any given axis, for example -90° on the z axis:

```
transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -90);
```